# tkInter function takes exactly 1 argument 2 given

Tags: binding, tkinter, typeerror

This seems to be a common issue, however I have one function which seems to work, and another which does not.  I get

```
TypeError:clicked() takes exactly one argument, two given
```

Where I have binded the clicked function to a Mouse Click.

However, the handler function, which is bound with protocal to the WM_DELETE_WINDOW event, seems to work fine. How are the two different? Thanks!

```
class GUI():
def __init__(self,root,fit_tuples):
    self.fit_tuples=fit_tuples
    self.root=root
    self.root.title("Beam Flux Registry")
    self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.handler)
    ...
    # Calendar Frame
    cal=Calendar(LeftFrame)
    cal.pack(side=TOP)
    cal.bind("<Button-1>",self.clicked)
    ...
    #Mainloop
    root.mainloop()

def clicked(self):
    print "%i/%i/%i"%(self.cal.selection.month,self.cal.selection.day,self.cal.selection.year)

def handler(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the [`Event`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) object in the `clicked()` method. When you `bind` a widget, the function that handles the binding will receive an object with attributes about the event that fired the function (ie, for a mouse-click event, you'll receive an object with attributes for the cursor's x and y).

The other method works because `protocol` isn't passing any arguments to the handler.

Comment: Thanks!  Another issue in this is now popping up.  If I try to access the cal variable in the clicked function, lets say 
    self.cal.selection 
I get the following "GUI instance has no attribute cal", but if I   remove the self and simply use
    cal.selection
As I would expect the function can read local instance variables, I get "global name cal not defined"
How do I access this instance variable outside of the constructor?
Thanks!

Comment: When you create the Calendar instance, you need to make it an instance variable. `self.cal = Calendar()`. Then you can access it in other methods of the class.